# Share GitLab Kubernetes Agent across multiple projects

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

With the help of [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223061), we deployed and use GitLab Kubernetes Agents.

Right now, when we have one project, let's say `gitlab.com/projectone/firstrepo`, we have a folder `.gitlab/agents/some-first-agent/config.yml` with content:

```yaml
gitops:
  manifest_projects:
    - id: projectone/firstrepo
      ref:
        branch: main
      default_namespace: the-namespace
      paths:
        - glob: 'manifest.yml'
```

We go to "Operate" tab, then click on "Kubernetes Cluster", then "Connect a cluster (Agent)", and this is working fine, happy.

Now we also have let's say `gitlab.com/projecttwo/secondrepo`, `gitlab.com/projectthree/thirdrepo` all the way to all the way to `gitlab.com/projectsixty/sixtiethrepo`, each with its own `.gitlab/agents/some-X-agent/config.yml`.

While working fine, we are quickly overwhelmed with the number of GitLab Kubernetes Agent pods in our Kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to reuse, share GitLab Kubernetes Agents between projects? How?

I tried:

```yaml
gitops:
  manifest_projects:
    - id: projectone/firstrepo
      ref:
        branch: main
      default_namespace: the-namespace
      paths:
        - glob: 'manifest.yml'
    - id: projecttwo/secondrepo
      ref:
        branch: main
      default_namespace: the-namespace
      paths:
        - glob: 'manifest.yml'
[...]
    - id: projectsixty/sixtyrepo
      ref:
        branch: main
      default_namespace: the-namespace
      paths:
        - glob: 'manifest.yml'
```

However, this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projects must have the same root group:

- config for use in CI/CD pilelines: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#authorize-the-agent-to-access-your-projects
- config for use with gitops (deprecated): https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops/agent.html#gitops-configuration-reference
  In the initial versions the manifest projects had to share a common root group and the manifests projects had to be public.

Gitlab has done some work to [manage manifest projects outside of the Agent configuration project](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7704), but has since decided to use [flux](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/gitops.html) instead.